# Layout issue with XeTeX and feynmp

Tags: xetex

I am trying to include Feynman graphics to my XeTeX document. Here is the `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[twoside,titlepage,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage{feynmp}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{eps}{*}{}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=eqs,placement={tbp},name=Éq.]{eq}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{table}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{eq}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:qq}}[.3\linewidth]{  
\begin{fmffile}{qq}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,65)
   \fmfleft{i1,i2} 
   \fmfright{o1,o2} 

   \fmflabel{q}{i1}
   \fmflabel{$\bar{\text{q}}$}{i2}
   \fmflabel{$\bar{\text{t}}$}{o1}
   \fmflabel{t}{o2}   

   \fmf{gluon,label=g}{v1,v2} 
   \fmf{quark}{i1,v1}
   \fmf{quark}{v1,i2} 
   \fmf{quark}{o1,v2}
   \fmf{quark}{v2,o2} 

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
   }\quad
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:gg1}}[.3\linewidth]{  
\begin{fmffile}{gg1}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,65)
   \fmfleft{i1,i2} 
   \fmfright{o1,o2} 

   \fmflabel{g}{i1}
   \fmflabel{g}{i2}
   \fmflabel{$\bar{\text{t}}$}{o1}
   \fmflabel{t}{o2}   

   \fmf{gluon,label=g}{v1,v2} 
   \fmf{gluon}{i1,v1}
   \fmf{gluon}{i2,v1} 
   \fmf{quark}{o1,v2}
   \fmf{quark}{v2,o2} 

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
   }\quad
\subcaptionbox{\label{fig:gg2}}[.3\linewidth]{  
   \label{fig:gg2}
\begin{fmffile}{gg2}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,65)
   \fmfleft{i1,i2} 
   \fmfright{o1,o2} 

   \fmflabel{g}{i1}
   \fmflabel{g}{i2}
   \fmflabel{$\bar{\text{t}}$}{o1}
   \fmflabel{t}{o2}   

   \fmf{gluon}{i1,v1}
   \fmf{quark}{o1,v1} 
   \fmf{gluon}{v2,i2}
   \fmf{quark}{v2,o2} 
   \fmf{quark,label=t}{v1,v2} 
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
}
\label{fig:prod2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As I am using the `feynmp`package (not `feynmp-auto`), I run:

```
latexmk -quiet -e '$pdflatex=q/xelatex %O %S/' -f -pdf -synctex=1 -jobname=Document -outdir=$PWD/Result $PWD/main.tex
cd Result
mpost qq.mp
mpost gg1.mp
mpost gg2.mp
cd ..
latexmk -quiet -e '$pdflatex=q/xelatex %O %S/' -f -pdf -synctex=1 -jobname=Document -outdir=$PWD/Result $PWD/main.tex
```

and I get this:

[image]

As you can see, gluon propagators are truncated and their labels overlap them. Would you have any suggestion to fix this ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. It's helpful to post complete minimal documents rather than just fragments; then people can compile them quickly and don't have to figure out which packages you are using.

Comment: Thanks Alan ; I've completed the fragment so that it compiles.

Comment: It's a problem I already met with: some EPS files are not imported correctly in XeLaTeX.

Comment: My impression is that the bounding box for `gg1.1` and `gg2.1` are not set correctly, because if I convert them to PDF, the result is truncated like in your picture.